# JS as Array property in Object single instance

Tags: javascript, arrays

Been searching for a while to fully understand how arrays works in object. I am familiar with other languages but this causes a lot of confusion for me.
Having an object

```
var Test = {
    TestArray: [],
}
var a = Object.create(Test);
var b = Object.create(Test);
```

From my expectation this should create 2 instances of the object and having 2 different arrays however having an array inside behave like 1 instance adding values to the array affects both instances could anyone explain why?

Comment: `Test` isn't a class, it's an object. All you're doing is creating two objects `a` and `b` with the same shared prototype `Test`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right about `2 instances of the object`, but inside they have the same array reference, therefore mutating it in one place will mutate it in another place.

```
var Test = {
    TestArray: [],
}

var a = Object.create(Test);
var b = Object.create(Test);

a === b // false
a.TestArray === a.TestArray // true
```

There are quite a lot of ways to avoid this problem. Below is an option in order to keep `Object.create`

```
var getTest = () => ({
    TestArray: [],
});

var a = Object.create(getTest());
var b = Object.create(getTest());
```

Comment: Is there a other way to create array or the obect so they dont have same reference?

Answer (score 3):

You are right, [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) is creating a new object, but whenever you pass an object to it, it makes that object as a prototype of it.

Meaning, if that prototype object as an array, the will share the same instance.

Check out the example given in MDN, the function that they call is on the prototype, therefore there is only one instance of it.

In order to gain your request, you can use ES6 class syntax:

```js
class Test {
  constructor() {
    this.TestArray = [];
  }
}

const t1 = new Test();
const t2 = new Test();

t1.TestArray.push('item1');
console.log(t1.TestArray);
console.log(t2.TestArray); // Should print an empty array
```